# Converting 9-bit binary to floating point number

Tags: computer-science, data-representation

1. The exponent field employs a bias of 15. Decode the 9-bit, normalized, binary number into its normalized decimal value: 110001101 (show steps please)
2. Assume the same format. Determine the bit pattern for the decimal number 2.25.

First show the binary representation then show each component of the floating point number separately and how you got it.

Comment: depends on how many exponent bits and how many significand bits there are.  Also whether or not there is a sign bit.

Comment: Looks like a [homework question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions)